# jquery combobox +set selected value to a combobox array

Tags: php, jquery, selected

I was asked to work on a php application that has been created by someone else.

In the page there is a table that display rows of data with each row having the same cells names
e.i: responsibles[]

I would like to set the combobox responsibles[] of the row that is being generated to a value i.e: "name2" how is it possible do to that.
The code below generates the combobox for a row.

```
 <?php

                        $responsibleCmb = '<td style="width:180px; min-width: 180px;" <select id="responsibles[]"
                    name="responsibles[]" style="width:180px; height:16px;">
>                   <option>-</option>';
>                   // Get all the employees that have a role id of 1 (Auditor) and display an option for each one
>                   if (isset ( $data ['employees'] )) {
>                       while ( $rowCmb = $data ['employees']->fetch_assoc () ) {
>                           // The value of the option is their employee id
>     $responsibleCmb.=          "<option value='". $rowCmb['FirstLast']. "'";
> 
>     $responsibleCmb.=                          ">$rowCmb[FirstLast]</option>";
>                       }
>                       }
>     $responsibleCmb.=          "</select></td>";
>           
>                       
>                   while ( $row = $this->data ['filtered']->fetch_assoc () ) {
>                       ?>
>                           <tr>
>                       <td style="font-size: 7.5pt; width: 60px; min-width: 60px;"><a
>                           href='<?=ROOT?>demerit/view?id=<?=$row['id']?>'>
>                                       <?=$row['id']?>
>                                   </a> <input type="hidden" value="<?=$row['id']?>" name="ids[]">
>                       </td>
>                       <td style="font-size: 8pt; width: 100px; min-width: 100px;">
>                                   <?php $description = explode(';', $row['model_main_code']);?>
>                                       <?=$description[0]?>
>                                       <hr
>                               style="margin: 0 auto; border-top-style: dashed; border-top-color: black;">
>                                       <?=$description[1]?>
>                               </td>
>                       <td><textarea class="expand" name="actions[]"><?=$row['action']?></textarea>
>                       </td>
>                            <!--               //********************************************                           --> <!--               // PRINT COMBOBOX FOR RESPONSIBLE SO THAT USER CAN'T TYPE IN A WRONG NAME.                           --> <!--
>               //******************************************** -->
>                   <?php 
>                       echo($responsibleCmb);
>                   ?>
> 
> 
> Then when i enter the td of the comobobx
> 
> <?php echo($responsibleCmb); ?>
> 
> 
> <script> $("responsibles[]").val('Doina Angheluta'); </script>
```

Included is the output of my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/v2quyxp3/

Thanks for your help.

also i tried this method instead of storing the combobox code in the $responsibleCmb variable but  then it would fill up only the combobox on the first row.

```
                            echo '<td><select id="responsibles[]"
                                name="responsibles[]" style="width:180px;">
                                <option>-</option>';
                                // Get all the employees that have a role id of 1 (Auditor) and display an option for each one
                        if (isset ( $data ['employees'] )) {
                            while ( $rowCmb = $data ['employees']->fetch_assoc () ) {
                                // The value of the option is their employee id
                                echo "<option value='". $rowCmb['FirstLast']. "'";
                                if ($row ['responsible'] ==  $rowCmb['FirstLast']) {
                                echo ' selected=\'true\'';
                                }
                                echo ">$rowCmb[FirstLast]</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        echo "</select></td>";
```

Comment: Are you asking how you should determine whether a name should be selected or how to signify a selected option through HTML? If the later, refer to this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)

Comment: I'm asking, when i loop througb the dataset of data

while ( $row = $this->data ['filtered']->fetch_assoc () ) {
>                       ?>

How can i set the value of a combobox if its name exists more than once in the form "Responsibles[]"

I know usually i can do     $("responsibles[]").val('Doina Angheluta') but since the id shows more than once in the webpage is there a way for me to set only the one of the row that the php code is writting?

Comment: Having the same ID on multiple elements is bad practice. Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.

Comment: I agree with you @DannyS3, i wouldn't have done it this way myself as there are more bad practices "like using 2 table fields as non unique key" i'm not the person who started the project but am not stuck with it now and trying to implement quick fix to provide the user with the modification they request.

Comment: At to create the combobox i tried to loop though the employee recordset

     while ( $rowCmb = $data ['employees']->fetch_assoc ()

 then validate if the new combobox option is equal to the selected value in the database.

if ($row ['responsible'] ==  $rowCmb['FirstLast']) ...

But doing so fills only the first record on the webpage, like if the ['employees'] wouldn't reset to the first record on the dataset when i hit that line of code on the second and further loops.